# when there is an exception, roll back complete operation but store the exception in table

Tags: java, model-view-controller, java-8

I have been using try catch from very long but problem with the try catch is, if any exception happens in try, it will go to catch and i save the exception in of the table using catch method, issue here is, it will not roll back complete process because of the try, so how to roll back with storing the exception in table

```
Element rootElement = request.addElement("Cm-CreateFA");
rootElement.addElement("fieldActivityType").addText(faType_id.getIdValue().trim());
rootElement.addElement("createdBy").addText("SE");
rootElement.addElement("isEligibleForDispatch").addText("true");
rootElement.addElement("fieldActivityStatus").addText("P");
rootElement.addElement("dispatchGroup").addText(dispatch_Group_Cd.trim());
rootElement.addElement("user").addText(getActiveContextUser().getId().getIdValue().trim());
rootElement.addElement("scheduleDateTimeStart").addText(scheduleDate);
rootElement.addElement("creationDateTime").addText(getSystemDateTime().toString());
rootElement.addElement("servicePointId").addText(disco_ServicePoint_Id.getIdValue().trim());



try{

response = BusinessObjectDispatcher.execute(request,BusinessObjectActionLookup.constants.ADD);
rootElement = response.getRootElement();


} 


catch (Exception e) {
try{
    addError(CmMessageRepository.faCantbeCreated());
}
catch(Error execp){
System.out.println("<<=======in exception=========>>"); 

}
finally{
 String errorMessage=e.initCause(e.getCause()).toString();
 genericBComponet.addSyncInboundBoLog(in_Sync_Id, errorMessage, chartype11);
 genericBComponet.updateSyncinCharValues(new SyncRequestInbound_Id(in_Sync_Id),charType8,"Y");
}
}
```

Comment: what kind of a process are you looking to rollback? and why in the first place do you want to put exceptions in some table and ignore?

Comment: i am creating some activity, so if any exception occurs while creating activity, i want to roll back also, i want to store the exact exception in some table, i thought with try catch i can do this but try catch doesnt roll back the process because of the error handling

Comment: Would be better understood looking at the code, please do add a proper MCVE for  people to help.

Comment: added, please check

Answer (score 1):

If your try-catch is supposed to be responsible for the transaction boundary, then you'd likely want to code it like this:

```
try (Connection conn = /*get connection*/) {
    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        // do work here
        conn.commit();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        conn.rollback();
        saveException(conn, e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Where the `saveException` method commits immediately (or auto-commits).

Comment: is it okay to use hibernate session.rollback instead connection.rollback?

Comment: @RajeshAcharya Question didn't say Hibernate or anything, so I just defaulted to plain JDBC. So yeah, you should use Hibernate session, if you use Hibernate.